# Banner ad Crashes due to initialisation

Tags: android, banner-ads

I am having problems adding banner ads in my android app. I just copied the code off the documentation from the website, I can seem to figure out what I am not doing. The app keeps crashing. I have the code below in Mainactivity.java

```
private AdView mAdView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And my Manifest looks as shown below

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
            <meta-data
                android:name="preloaded_fonts"
                android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-admod_generated number"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Code for the page where the ad appears look as shown below

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/FlashcardimageView"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="290dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FlashcardTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Mark"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/atma_semibold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.544"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.853" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error message from Debug terminal is as shown below

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xtenalyze.android.myapplication, PID: 15281
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
    * to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
    * Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
    ******************************************************************************
    
    
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7828)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7364)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:293)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2151)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8283)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: type here
```

Can anyone look into the code and offer assistance? Thanking everyone for their time and offer to help.

A review of my code, hopefully to find errors

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you put the ID in the wrong place in your manifest. Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) linked in that error message, it should go at the application level, not the activity level. You should change

```
<application>
  <activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-admod_generated number"/>
    // other stuff
  </activity>
</application>
```

to this

```
<application>
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
      android:value="ca-app-pub-admod_generated number"/>

  <activity>
    // other stuff
  </activity>
</application>
```